# Query nested document with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I know this question has been asked a lot of times but I'm kinda new to mongo and mongoose as well and I couldn't figure it out !

My problem:

I have a which looks like this:

```
var rankingSchema = new Schema({
    userId : { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User' },
    pontos : {type: Number, default:0},
    placarExato : {type: Number, default:0},
    golVencedor : {type: Number, default:0},
    golPerdedor : {type: Number, default:0},
    diferencaVencPerd : {type: Number, default:0},
    empateNaoExato : {type: Number, default:0},
    timeVencedor : {type: Number, default:0},
    resumo : [{
        partida : { type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Partida' },
        palpite : [Number],
        quesito : String
    }]
});
```

Which would return a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("539d0756f0ccd69ac5dd61fa"),
    "diferencaVencPerd" : 0,
    "empateNaoExato" : 0,
    "golPerdedor" : 0,
    "golVencedor" : 1,
    "placarExato" : 2,
    "pontos" : 78,
    "resumo" : [ 
        {
            "partida" : ObjectId("5387d991d69197902ae27586"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("539d07eb06b1e60000c19c18"),
            "palpite" : [ 
                2, 
                0
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "partida" : ObjectId("5387da7b27f54fb425502918"),
            "quesito" : "golsVencedor",
            "_id" : ObjectId("539d07eb06b1e60000c19c1a"),
            "palpite" : [ 
                3, 
                0
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "partida" : ObjectId("5387dc012752ff402a0a7882"),
            "quesito" : "timeVencedor",
            "_id" : ObjectId("539d07eb06b1e60000c19c1c"),
            "palpite" : [ 
                2, 
                1
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "partida" : ObjectId("5387dc112752ff402a0a7883"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("539d07eb06b1e60000c19c1e"),
            "palpite" : [ 
                1, 
                1
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "partida" : ObjectId("53880ea52752ff402a0a7886"),
            "quesito" : "placarExato",
            "_id" : ObjectId("539d07eb06b1e60000c19c20"),
            "palpite" : [ 
                1, 
                2
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "partida" : ObjectId("53880eae2752ff402a0a7887"),
            "quesito" : "placarExato",
            "_id" : ObjectId("539d0aa82fb219000054c84f"),
            "palpite" : [ 
                2, 
                1
            ]
        }
    ],
    "timeVencedor" : 1,
    "userId" : ObjectId("539b2f2930de100000d7356c")
}
```

My question is, first: How can I filter the resumo nested document by quesito ? Is it possible to paginate this result, since this array is going to increase. And last question, is this a nice approach to this case ?

Thank you guys !

Comment: Does this not return like this already? You seem to have mixed both embedded and referenced designs here. While you do provide an external object reference you also appear to have defined the contained fields as in embedded structure. How are you actually saving your data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted, your schema implies that you actually have embedded data even though you are storing an external reference. So it is not clear if you are doing both embedding and referencing or simply embedding by itself.

The big caveat here is the difference between matching a "document" and actually filtering the contents of an array. Since you seem to be talking about "paging" your array results, the large focus here is on doing that, but still making mention of the warnings.

Multiple "filtered" matches in an array requires the aggregation framework. You can generally "project" the single match of an array element, but this is needed where you expect more than one:

```
Ranking.aggregate(
    [ 
        // This match finds "documents" that "contain" the match
        { "$match": { "resumo.quesito": "value" } },

        // Unwind de-normalizes arrays as documents
        { "$unwind": "$resumo" },

        // This match actually filters those document matches
        { "$match": { "resumo.quesito": "value" } },

        // Skip and limit for paging, which really only makes sense on single
        // document matches
        { "$skip": 0 },
        { "$limit": 2 },

        // Return as an array in the original document if you really want
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "otherField": { "$first": "$otherField" },
            "resumo": { "$push": "$resumo" }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {


    }
)
```

Or the MongoDB 2.6 way by "filtering" inside a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) using the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator. But still you need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) in order to "page" array positions, but there is possibly less processing as the array is "filtered" first:

```
Ranking.aggregate(
    [ 
        // This match finds "documents" that "contain" the match
        { "$match": { "resumo.quesito": "value" } },

        // Filter with $map
        { "$project": {
              "otherField": 1,
              "resumo": {
                  "$setDifference": [
                      {
                          "$map": {
                              "input": "$resumo",
                              "as": "el",
                              "in": { "$eq": ["$$el.questio", "value" ] }
                          }
                      },
                      [false]
                  ]
              }
        }},          

        // Unwind de-normalizes arrays as documents
        { "$unwind": "$resumo" },

        // Skip and limit for paging, which really only makes sense on single
        // document matches
        { "$skip": 0 },
        { "$limit": 2 },

        // Return as an array in the original document if you really want
        { "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "otherField": { "$first": "$otherField" },
            "resumo": { "$push": "$resumo" }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {


    }
)
```

The inner usage of [**`$skip`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) here really only makes sense when you are processing a single document and just "filtering" and "paging" the array. It is possible to do this with multiple documents, but is very involved as there is no way to just "slice" the array. Which brings us to the next point.

Really with embedded arrays, for paging that does not require any filtering you just use the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator, which was designed for this purpose:

```
Ranking.find({},{ "resumo": { "$slice": [0,2] } },function(err,docs) {

});
```

Your alternate though is to simply reference the documents in the external collection and then pass the arguments to mongoose [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) to filter and "page" the results. The change in the schema itself would just be:

```
    "resumo": [{ "type": "Schema.Types.ObjectId", "ref": "Partida" }]
```

With the external referenced collection now holding the object detail rather than embedding directly in the array. The use of [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate) with filtering and paging is:

```
 Ranking.find().populate({
     "path": "resumo",
     "match": { "questio": "value" },
     "options": { "skip": 0, "limit": 2 }
 }).exec(function(err,docs) {

     docs = docs.filter(function(doc) {
         return docs.comments.length;   
     });
 });
```

Of course the possible problem there is that you can no longer actually query for the documents that contain the "embedded" information as it is now in another collection. This results in pulling in all documents, though possibly by some other query condition, but then manually testing them to see if they were "populated" by the filtered query that was sent to retrieve those items.

So it really does depend on what you are doing and what your approach is. If you regularly intend to "search" on inner arrays then embedding will generally suit you better. Also if you really only interesting in "paging" then the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator works well for this purpose with embedded documents. But beware growing embedded arrays too large.

Using a referenced schema with mongoose helps with some size concerns, and there is methodology in place to assist with "paging" results and filtering them as well. The drawback is that you can no longer query "inside" those elements from the parent itself. So parent selection by the inner elements is not well suited here. Also keep in mind that while not all of the data is embedded, there is still the reference to the `_id` value of the external document. So you can still end up with large arrays, which may not be desirable.

For anything large, consider that you will likely be doing the work yourself, and working backwards from the "child" items to then match the parent(s).

Comment: Thanks man, that worked, but I decided to change my schema, so it would be better and faster to query !

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure that you can filter sub-document directly with mongoose. However you can get the parent document with `Model.find({'resumo.quesito': 'THEVALUE'})` (you should also and an index on it)

Then when you have the parent you can get the child by comparing the quesito

Additionnal doc can be found here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: I don't see how this was useful, I already know that and I asked using mongoose. Thanks !